# Mostrar datos Mysql en TEXTAREA

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL, tengo un formulario muy simple en donde tengo algunos input y un Textarea, cuando edito la información de un formulario, mi sistema me muestra toda la información en los Input pero no logro que me muestre datos en el Textarea. He realizado pruebas como cambiar las etiquetas del textarea por input y en ese caso si me muestra la informacion. He buscado en distintas paginas y foros pero no he logrado resolverlo.
Mi codigo es el sigueinte:

```
 <?php
  require_once('includes/load.php');
 ?>

 <?php
 $pasantia = find_by_id('pasantia',(int)$_GET['id']);

 if(!$pasantia){
  $session->msg("d","Missing product id.");
  redirect('pasantia.php');
 }
 ?>

  <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <form method="post" action="editar_pasantia.php?id=<?php echo (int)$pasantia['id'] ?>">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i>
              </span>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo 
   remove_junk($pasantia['id']);?>">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_docente" 
  placeholder="Nombre del/la Profesional" value="<?php echo 
  remove_junk($pasantia['nombre_docente']);?>">
           </div>
          </div>

  <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                  </span>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="observaciones" name="observaciones" 
      placeholder="Observaciones..." rows="6" maxlength="500" value="<?php echo 
      remove_junk($pasantia['observaciones']);?>"></textarea> 
                </div>
              
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

MI tabla:

```
1   id Primaria int(50)     
2   nombre_docente  varchar(50) 
3   observaciones   varchar(1000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los cuadros de texto (textarea) no tienen la propiedad `value`, solo se pone el valor entre la etiqueta de apertura y cierre:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="observaciones" name="observaciones" 
  placeholder="Observaciones..." rows="6" maxlength="500"><?php echo 
  remove_junk($pasantia['observaciones']);?></textarea>
```

Comment: MUCHASSSSS GRACIASSSSSS, eso era. Te lo agradezco